# How do Java arrays implement Cloneable?

Tags: java, arrays, clone

From [the documentation of `Object#clone()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#clone--):

> Note that all arrays are considered to implement the interface `Cloneable`. Otherwise, this method creates a new instance of the class of this object and initializes all its fields with exactly the contents of the corresponding fields of this object, as if by assignment; the contents of the fields are not themselves cloned. Thus, this method performs a "shallow copy" of this object, not a "deep copy" operation.

But [the documentation of `java.util.Arrays`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) doesn't indicate that `Arrays implements Cloneable`.

How do arrays implement `Cloneable`?

Comment: The java.util.Arrays class is not the base class for array instances. In fact, all its methods are static, and it does not implement the Cloneable interface.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are confusing `java.util.Arrays`, a normal class that contains methods to work with arrays, and arrays themselves, which are a rather special construct in the Java language but are nonetheless objects with a synthetic class. This is this class that implements `Cloneable`. It also derives directly from `Object`. Look at the [JLS page on arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html) which is pretty clear on the subject.

Look for example at this code (taken from the aforementionned JLS):

```
class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] ia = new int[3];
        System.out.println(ia.getClass());
        System.out.println(ia.getClass().getSuperclass());
    }
}
```

This will print:

```
class [I
class java.lang.Object
```

Comment: Will I get some document to refer arrays just like how we have Java Docs for Array class?

Comment: @user2488578 Closest that I am aware of is: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/arrays.html

Comment: The best reference is the page I mentioned. A Javadoc for arrays would be quite short, its only members (except the ones inherited from Object) are `length` and its implementation of `clone()`.

Answer (score 5):

`java.util.Arrays` is a class containing utilities that operate on Java arrays, and is not to be confused with arrays themselves.

An array is a container object that holds a fixed number of values of a single type. They are a special type of Object defined explicitly in the Java language. All Java arrays implement `java.lang.Cloneable` and `java.io.Serializable`.

`java.util.Arrays`, on the other hand, does not implement these interfaces, and only provides static methods that implement common functions performed on arrays.

When you clone a single dimensional array, such as `Object[]`, a "deep copy" is performed with the new array containing copies of the original array's elements as opposed to references.

A clone of a multidimensional array (like `Object[][]`) is a "shallow copy" however, which is to say that it creates only a single new array with each element array a reference to an original element array.